# Where is "views.py"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, python-3.7

Him I am trying to set up my first django project. I have never done Django before so I don't know anything about it. I am trying to follow the official Django tutorial page, it tells me to open `views.py`. I can't find it anywhere in my "mysite" folder. In it, I have `manage.py` , `db.sqlite3`, `__init__.py`, `settings.py`, `urls.py` and `wsgi.py` along with the **pycache** folder, but no signs of views.py. Can anyone help me?

Comment: the views belongs to an app inside your site. Maybe you have missed the step to create an app ?

Comment: ok, ive not created an app, thanks

Comment: oh, I missed out the line  `python manage.py startapp polls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this command in console `django-admin startproject myfirstproject` will create a new `django` project for you, which will have another sub-folder named same as your project name. By default on creating a new project, the `views.py` file isn't created you have to create it `manually` in your project sub-folder.

To create a new app, Run `django-admin startapp myapp` which will create a new sub-folder under your parent directory which will have `views.py` where you can write your own custom views for your HTML templates

Comment: Enjoy Django 